# Qt: Force size of QDockWidget

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qt5, c++14

I have a `QMainWindow` with a center widget and a number of dockable widgets. The size of the various widgets get manipulated by the sliders between the dockables. I would like to fix the  center widget's height to it's `minimumSize` height and not allow it to be made larger by the user. The width should remain relative to the `QMainWindow` (I only allow top and bottom dockables, so the center widget is stretched to the width of the main window).

The center widget is a `QDockWidget`, containing a `QWidget` with a `QVBoxLayout` (containing more stuff).

I have tried deriving from the `QVBoxLayout` and overriding `maximumSize`, but it wasn't respected. Overriding `expandingDirections` also didn't make any difference.

Any advise on how to achieve this?

Comment: Setting a maximum height on the widget() of the dock widget should help

Answer (score 0):

Got it, thanks to Johannes Schaub.

I thought the `QDockWidget` propagates the constraints to its contained widget, which it does not. Setting maximumHeight on the inner Widget does the trick.